# Why is every process creating the same object multiple times?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to generate 2 different holograms simultaneously, so have tried using multiprocessing to save time. The 'BinaryPhase' object should generate a different hologram every time it's called.

However, when I do this, the array that is supposed to contain the two different holograms instead contains 2 of the same hologram.

I have seen many implementations of using multiprocessing to write to array online and I can not see why mine is doing this.

I am also quite certain that it is to do specifically with the calling of the initialisation function of the BinaryPhase object, since if I add a line to the 'getHologram' function to print a random number, the numbers are different for each process.

However, I do not see why random.uniform(0,1) would execute differently in each process (as you would expect) but the BinaryPhase(...) would not.

Edit: I should also add that the same code with Process changed to Thread works, though obviously much more slowly. I know vaguely that threads share memory, and processes do not, but cannot think of why this would cause the same object to be generated in different processes. If anyone is familiar with these things then an explanation would be very useful!

```
def getHologram(image, depth, distance):
    newHologram = BinaryPhase(image,depth,distance)
    holograms.append(newHologram)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    holograms = Manager().list()
    processes = []

    for i in range(2):
            p = Process(target=getHologram, args=('./images/topRightSquare.bmp',1,1,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
            p.join()

    holograms = list(holograms)
```

Comment: How does `BinaryPhase` create different holograms with the same parameters? Random values? Are you seeding in `BinaryPhase`?

Comment: Yes, random values are used in the generation of the holograms. I have tried seeding with time.time_ns as the seed value and it still produces the same holograms though.

Comment: Showing us the `__init__` with the actual seeding code within `BinaryPhase` and adding a `print(seed)` inside `BinaryPhase` for debugging could help. Which Python version are you using?